# Is it a good idea to write wrapper around elastic search or solr

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, architecture, soa, microservices

We recently migrated from solr to elastic search.
So decision was taken to write a wrapper in custom query format, which converts to elastic search queries.In future if we change to another data store we just have to modify this api but not all applications. Is it good decision from architecture point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, the search engine should be encapsulated just like any other data store.  Think about as if it were a database.

Comment: But it is becoming single point of failure,Any issue in the future can lead to disaster in the future, More over it takes away the ability to write complex and various types of queries supported by elastic search.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's a good idea to have wrapper around it.
It will help you to have different databases in future with minimal modification.

In future you may replace it with lucene or you may want to go for any nosql database like mongodb.